# Passing value from controller to html in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Hello I have a simple web page where I have a button and a text near to button. I need to change text when button clicked and get the new text from code.

This is controller class from where I need to pass response:

```
@GetMapping("/stream")
    public String openStream(Model model) { 
        String response = service.openStream();
        model.addAttribute("stream", response);     
        return "mainpage";
    }
```

And here my html page, the value from controller must be instead of question marks:

```
<div id="container">
  <button class="button"
        onclick="window.location.href = '/stream';">Stream</button>
  <p align="center">?????</p>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit:
I tried ${stream}
but getting it as text not value, please see screenshot:
[image]

Edit 2: 
 I need pass String from the text area to doc variable in the controller. Please help.

HTML:

```
<div>
<textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="description"></textarea>
button class="button" onclick="window.location.href ='/send';">Send</button>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/send")
public String send(String doc) {

    service.sendDoc(doc);

    return "mainpage";
}
```

Comment: `<p align="center">${stream}</p>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
<p align="center">?????</p>
```

To

```
<p align="center">${stream}</p> OR <p th:text="${stream}"></p>
```

*How it is working?*

**You can access variables value by ${key}.**

*Example*

```
model.addAttribute("key", value);
```

Get value by `${key}` in HTML

> In Thymeleaf, these model attributes (or context variables in
>   Thymeleaf jargon) can be accessed with the following syntax:
>   `${attributeName}`, where attributeName in our case is `stream`. This
>   is a Spring EL expression. In short, Spring EL (Spring Expression
>   Language) is a language that supports querying and manipulating an
>   object graph at runtime.

***UPDATE***

*The th:field attribute can be used on input, select, or, textarea.*

Replace  `<p align="center">?????</p>` with

```
<input type="text" id="stream" name="stream" th:value="${stream}" />
```

OR

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{stream}" />`
```

OR

```
<input type="text" id="stream" name="stream" th:field="*{stream}" th:value="${stream}" />
```

Also try  `<p th:inline="text">[[${stream}]]</p>`; `<p data-th-text="${stream}"` />

[Thymeleaf Document](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html) [Thymeleaf Document Inputs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#inputs)

---

***UPDATE 2***

*Get value from Thymeleaf to Spring Boot*

```
<form th:action="@{/send}" method="get">
   <textarea  th:name="doc" rows="10" cols="100" name="doc"></textarea>
   <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

    @GetMapping("/send")
    public String send(@RequestParam(name="doc", required = false) String doc) {
        //change required = false as per requirement
        System.out.println("Doc: "+doc);
        return "textarea-input";
    }
```

*Note: use "th:field" for Entity/Model*

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have editted question, please see.

Comment: Hello, yes I have tried.
<p th:text="${stream}"></p>  in this variant nothing appears.

Comment: @SamirAmanov please make sure your controller is getting invoked and you get a string response

Comment: Hello @SamirAmanov can you try with `<input type="text" th:field="*{stream}" th:value="${stream}" />` by replacing it with <p> tag as The th:field attribute can be used only with input, select, or, textarea.

Comment: @SamirAmanov Refer the updated answer and let me know the outcome

Comment: Show us the all the tags/text of your html before <head> tag.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Below shown line helped:
<p th:inline="text">[[${stream}]]</p>

Comment: Could you please advise how to pass from html to controller. In html I have a text area and need to pass the value from text area to controller as a string when send button clicked. Exactly vice versa of the operation you helped above.

Comment: Can you update the above question with your code and error if any?

Comment: Hello Patel, I have edited. Please check for Edit 2.

Comment: Hello @SamirAmanov, I have updated my answer, please refer update2. I have tested it on my machine and it is working fine

Comment: Welcome @SamirAmanov, please vote up the answer as the future reader can easily find the working solution

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your help. Below shown line helped:

```
<p th:inline="text">[[${stream}]]</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these  : `<p align="center">${stream}</p>` or `<p th:text="${stream}"></p>`

This tag may be causing a problem :

```
<button class="button"
        onclick="window.location.href = '/stream';">Stream</button>
```

Please check it by removing this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have editted question, please see.

Answer (score 0):

So i solve it like that :

let said i want to pass  `int ValueIwantToPass=5`

in my **controller** i put

```
@GetMapping("/tasks")
public String listTasks(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("value", ValueIwantToPass);
}
```

and in my HTML file it look

```
<h1>i wanted to pass [[${value}]]</h1>
```