# Spring Boot MVC passing variables to model always null in html

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I followed this code sample https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/spring-boot-restful.html to get a basic spring boot application working.
Now I want to add frontend components through thymleaf. Passing variables into the Model dont are always null in the outputted html

controller

```
@Controller
class IndexController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    fun index(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "brian") name: String, model: Model): String {
        model.addAttribute("name", name)
        model.addAttribute("title", "some title")
        return "index"
    }
}
```

resources/templates/index.html

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:text="${title}"></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="page-content">
    <h1 th:text="|Hello ${name}!|"></h1>
    <h2 th:text="|Welcome to ${title} application|"></h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

spring seems to a lot of things under the hood so maybe i missing something obvious.

and the build gradle

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.6.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.7.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.71"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.2.71"
}

group = "com.ghost"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

//extra["springCloudVersion"] = "Greenwich.SR1"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
//  implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter")
//  implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage")
//  implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth")
    implementation("org.springframework.session:spring-session-core")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

//dependencyManagement {
//  imports {
//      mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
//  }
//}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56991362/passing-value-from-controller-to-html-in-spring/56991562#56991562

Comment: I took your code, added the missing imports, removed the oauth2-client dependency since it would require additional security configuration in order to be able to log in, and everything works fine. So please provide a complete minimal example, tell precisely what you're doing, what you expect to happen and what happens instead.