# How to pass values to variables of a HTML template using Thymeleaf in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, sendgrid

I'm setting up an API to send e-mails. I am using the template engine from Thymeleaf to format the body of my e-mail.

I am unable to pass a value to variables in my HTML file.

I have tried using the `setVariable` function.

```java
Context context = new Context();

//context.setVariable("variable in html", "value to it");// set like this

context.setVariable("name", "ajay");
context.setVariable("date", "23rdfeb");
context.setVariable("rupee", 399);
String sendDay1Email = templateEngine.process("lifecyclemailer/sample", context);

oMessage.get().setText(sendDay1Email, true);
```

E-mail template:

```
Dear `${name}`, your pack will expire on `${date}` of `${rupee}`.
```

This is the e-mail I am supposed to be receiving.

E-mail template:

```
Dear Ajay, your pack will expire on 23rd Feb of 2019.
```

This is the e-mail I am expecting.

Comment: remove "$name" and replace with "name"

Comment: already tried this one, didn't work .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56991362/passing-value-from-controller-to-html-in-spring/56991562#56991562

Answer (score 1):

In general, Thymeleaf expressions are only processed in HTML tag attributes (like `<span th:text="${name}" />`) or inlined expressions (like `[[${name}]]`). Your template probably needs to look like this:

E-mail template:

```
Dear [[${name}]], your pack will be expired on [[${date}]] of [[${rupee}]].
```

(This is affected by how you've configured your template engine, but I think inlined expressions work in all modes.)